# EBCDIC to ASCII conversion, handling numeric values

Tags: c#, .net, ascii, ebcdic

I’m attempting to convert files from **ECDIC** to **ASCII** format and have run into an interesting issue. The files contain fixed length records with some fields being **signed binary integers** (described as B4 in the record layout), and **long-precision numeric** values (described as L8 in the record layout). I’ve been able to convert character data with no problem, but I’m not sure how to go about converting these numeric values. From a reference manual for the original system (an [IBM 5110](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/ibm/5110/SA21-9308-0_IBM_5110_BASIC_Reference_Manual_Jan78.pdf)), the fields are described below.

> B indicates the length  (2, 4, or 8 bytes) of numeric data items in 
>   fixed-point  signed binary integer format that are to be converted to
>   BASIC internal data  format.  For record I/O file input, the next 2,
>   4, or 8 bytes in  the record  contain a signed binary value to be
>   converted by the system into internal  data format and assigned to the
>   variable(s) specified in the READ FILE or  REREAD FILE statement using
>   a FORM statement.

and

> L indicates long-precision (8 characters) for numeric values.  For
>   input, this entry indicates  that an eight-position, long-precision
>   value in  the record is to be assigned without conversion to a
>   corresponding numeric  variable specified in the READ FILE or REREAD
>   FILE statement.

EDIT: Here's the code I'm using for the conversion

```
private void ConvertFile(EbcdicFile file)
{
    if (file == null) return;

    var filePath = Path.Combine(file.Path, file.FileName);
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        this.Logger.Info(string.Format("Cannot convert file {0}. It does not exist.", filePath));
        return;
    }

    var ebcdic = Encoding.GetEncoding(37);
    string convertedFilepath = Path.Combine(file.Path, file.ConvertedFileName);
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    if (!file.HasNumericFields)
        File.WriteAllBytes(convertedFilepath, Encoding.Convert(ebcdic, Encoding.ASCII, fileData));
    else
    {
        var convertedFileData = new List<byte>();
        for (int position = 0; position < fileData.Length; position += file.RecordLength)
        {
            var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(fileData, position, file.RecordLength);
            file.Fields.ForEach(field =>
                {
                    var fieldSegment = segment.Array.Skip(segment.Offset + field.Start - 1).Take(field.Length);
                    if (field.Type.Equals("string", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        convertedFileData.AddRange(
                            Encoding.Convert(ebcdic, Encoding.ASCII, fieldSegment.ToArray())
                            );
                    }
                    else if (field.Type.Equals("B4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        // Not sure how to convert this field
                    }
                    else if (field.Type.Equals("L8", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        // Not sure how to convert this field
                    }
                });
        }

        File.WriteAllBytes(convertedFilepath, convertedFileData.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have described your current situation, but not asked a question :-). I think you want to say "How do I convert B4 and L8 field types from data files written by IBM 5110 BASIC"....  You need to show us some example data (hex dump), and preferably also the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've figured out how to convert both fields. B4 fields are very straightforward. They are essentially a 4-byte array which can be converted to an integer.

```
//The IBM 5110 were big endian machines, so reverse the array 
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(by);

int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(by, 0);
```

The L8 fields are 8-bytes arrays that represented an [IBM Double Precision Float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture#Double-precision_64-bit). There are many ways this can be converted to an [IEEE 754 Float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). A few examples can be found at:

- [How To Read IBM 370 Data from a Binary File](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235856)
- [Transform between IEEE, IBM or VAX floating point number formats and bytes expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12363/Transform-between-IEEE-IBM-or-VAX-floating-point-n)

Here's the version I used based on guidance from the articles.

```
private double IbmFloatToDouble(byte[] value)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, value))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

    if (BitConverter.ToInt64(value, 0) == 0)
        return 0;

    int exponentBias = 64;
    int ibmBase = 16;
    double sign = 0.0D;

    int signValue = (value[0] & 0x80) >> 7;
    int exponentValue = (value[0] & 0x7f);
    double fraction1 = (value[1] << 16) + (value[2] << 8) + value[3];
    double fraction2 = (value[4] << 24) + (value[5] << 16) + (value[6] << 8) + value[7];
    double exponent24 = 16777216.0;             // 2^24
    double exponent56 = 72057594037927936.0;    // 2^56

    double mantissa1 = fraction1 / exponent24;
    double mantissa2 = fraction2 / exponent56;
    double mantissa = mantissa1 + mantissa2;
    double exponent = Math.Pow(ibmBase, exponentValue - exponentBias);

    if (signValue == 0) 
        sign = 1.0;
    else 
        sign = -1.0;

    return (sign * mantissa * exponent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first know the fixed record size.  Use FileStream.Read() to read one record worth of bytes.  Then Encoding.GetString() to convert it to a string.

Then fish the fields out of the record using String.SubString().  A B4 is simply a SubString call with a length of 4, L8 with a length of 8.  Further convert such a field to a number with Decimal.Parse().  You may have to divide the result, it wasn't clear what fixed-point multiplier is used.  Good odds for 100.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe what you've described is how I've implemented it. Albeit I'm processing each record as a byte array. I will take a look at using Decimal.Parse with a fixed-point multiplier. That's a good suggestion. Unfortunately, I only have documentation for record layouts and the output, so this is kind of trial and error.